# Pycharm PyQt4 Autocomplete Not Working for Virtualenv

Tags: python, autocomplete, pyqt4, pycharm

For the past couple of days I've tried to get Pycharm autocomplete working for PyQt4 when running a virtualenv on Ubuntu 14.04. The code works perfectly fine, it's just that all the imports are marked as red and I get zero autocomplete when writing code. So far I've tried:

- copying the the dist-packages directory to the virtualenv and marking it as a source directory. This makes the code work, but no autocomplete.
- Marking the original dist-packages as a source folder for the project without moving them. Code works, autocomplete doesn't
- invalidating caches and restarting Pycharm. No effect on anything

The funny thing: I have PyQt4 installed globally and when I use the interpreter at /usr/bin/python3.4 autocomplete works. Why?!?

So now I have two choices:

1. Using my main interpreter and cluttering my computer with all the random libraries I need to use for any PyQt4 project I might work on.
2. Create virtualenvs, have a cleaner operating system but no autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one final act of desperation I tried installing SIP and PyQt4 directly in the virtualenv and now autocomplete works! So basically I:

1. Activated the virtualenv through the command line
2. Made the dist-packages folder in the lib folder in the virtualenv. You can probably call this folder anything you want.
3. Added the dist-packages folder as a content root for Pycharm through settings/project structure
4. Installed SIP and PyQt4 in this folder by following the instructions on [this site](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html). I had to use sudo for both *make install* commands.
5. Invalidated caches and restarted and everything works just like it should!

I hope this helps someone else with the same problem so you can spend your time programming instead of fighting with this ridiculous issue.